# How do I assign a src attribute to the background-image of another element?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and am wanting to create a slider that changes its background image according to a src of another element in pure JS.
Here is a snippet of code:

```
x = 1;
function image2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("imagecounter").textContent;
    var image2 = document.getElementById("image2").src;
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
    if (x == 2){
        slider.style.imageBackground = "url('image2');"} 
    }
```

The purpose of the code is to establish a number that controls the slides and when the number changes, the image with a src element is exchanged with the backgroun-image of the div #slider.

full code: https://codepen.io/lucaslg20/pen/BeNGzv/

Comment: The style `imageBackground` does not exist, i believe you are looking for `backgroundImage`

Comment: @Snel23 I did, but the console says "TypeError: slider is null".

Comment: That's because slider is a classname, you are trying to get it by id

Comment: Oh... sure. i created an id with same name, but the error continues. Does "null" have anything related to var image2?

Comment: Please read my and Anis R's answers.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you messed up the assignment of the `backgroundImage` style:

It should be:

```
if (x == 2){
  slider.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + image2 + "')";
}
```

You need to *concatenate* the value of `image2` properly.

In addition, I checked out your codepen HTML. You are looking for:
`document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0]`

not

`document.getElementById("slider")`

for the variable "slider".

Answer (score 1):

Two main issues here:

1 - Your slider element has a **class** of slider instead of an ID, so `getElementbyId("slider")` cannot find it and returns null.

2 - This line:

```
slider.style.imageBackground = "url('image2');"
```

- There is no property called `imageBackground`, it is `backgroundImage`, or simply `background` (both work).
- `"url('image2')"` will return **the string "image2", not the variable's value**. You can replace this by:

.

```
"url('" + image2 + "')"
```

Or by

```
`url('${image2}')`.
```

Comment: +01: Basically a better wording of my answer. Either that, or it should have been a suggested edit...